# How to enable middle-mouse clicks on iFrames?

Tags: html, iframe, onclick

I have an iframe which simply displays a slideshow of our different products. It's hosted on the same server, it was just easier to use an iFrame.

Each slide contains a link to the current product on the slide, i couldn't use an href on the anchors, so instead i used " onclick='window.top.location.href =...' ". (This also prevents right clicks for the links.)

So my question is can i enable middle mouse clicks (and right clicks) for the links so that we can open them in a new tab, or would i have to go back to using an href.

Note - The reason i used onclick instead of href, was because with href the link would open inside the iframe instead of changing the top page. Is there another way to circumvent this and still keep normal clickability? Thanks in advance guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are not using a tag with target attribute?it will open link in new window.
 add target="_blank"

```
<a href="" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you - haha guess i had one of those moments. Cheers

Comment: Welcome happy coding :-)